# How to fix The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I'm working on a Asp.net project where I have created some user controls on page dynamically through LoadControl() on Page Object but when I try to do any postback through any page I get `"The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted."` even when I have set Viewstate of dynamically created control to false.

If you have faced this problem please tell me how you fixed it.

The stack trace is:-

```
[FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters. ]
   System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) +0
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) +77
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String serializedState) +4
   System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState) +37
   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +147

[ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 

[HttpException (0x80004005): The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.]
   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) +198
   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowViewStateError(Exception inner, String persistedState) +14
   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +251
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() +106
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() +43
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +8431
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +253
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +78
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +49
   ASP.contact_us_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\otherland_ecom\33f31476\6c5f9007\App_Web_zgmfrrfa.14.cs:0
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +100
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Comment: Sounds like a serialization issue - please provide more informations on how you've serialized your controls view state.

Comment: at what point in the lifecycle do you load the control, and are you loading it on all requests (not just !ispostback)?

Comment: The first place to check, given the exception, is what kind of types you serialize into viewstate on the prior request (not the postback that throws the exception). Something you put in the hidden field?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please make sure that the dynamic controls are loaded before Page_Load. You can load them in Page_Init. (No need to assign values as they will be assigned from the viewstate).

Answer (score 1):

Set EnableEventValidation to false in design page(.aspx)

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" EnableEventValidation="false" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

Comment: It's not a good idea. It's strongly recommended that you do not disable event validation. This feature reduces the risk of unauthorized or malicious postback requests and callbacks

Comment: This does not work for me. All I have is to runat=server textareas

Answer (score 0):

I think u have added the control after page_load method.
when you add control it add the hidden field which is try to mach it when page post back it does not mach with the initial hidden field so it rise the error to when you add control dynamically try to remove its hidden field then it will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I've swapped Viestate storage for Session and this issue disappeared. When Session expires my login expires so the page is forced to reload and stay valid:

```
//ViewState["startConversion"] = false;
Session["startConversion"] = false;
```

Or

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfStartConversion" runat="server" />
```